# How to secure javascript-based game

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, security

My javascript-based game is using three main variables, which at the end are send to .php file, there they are (I think) validated and finally insterted into database.

My question is - how could I prevent my game from simply $_POST data pushing to server? Are there any possibilities to do this? I don't have any login forms or user panel there, just go on this side and play.

I thought about generating some kind of key or code at the beginning, get it through AJAX from PHP, play game, send it back and compare to expected results. What about this?

Comment: You can't trust any values sent from the user. So the only way you could guarantee the variables are correct would be to run an instance of your game on the server, and have the user send their actions to it. That way even if the user cheats client side, the server will reject the data because it won't match the expect results from the server instance of the game.

Comment: No matter what you do, a user could just copy all your client-side code, modify it to their will, and run their own version. Hidden keys, encryption, and other fancy stuff all become useless. For this reason, Supericy's suggestion is the only correct answer (this is what MMO games do)

Comment: without accountability there can be no enforcement.

Comment: @dandavis no need for accountability. For example, if you have a person object which can move, and the server sees them move 30 metres in 2 seconds, it can say "nope". It doesn't care *who* they are.